# Wildfly and spring-boot: Failed to register application at spring-boot-admin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly

Upon copying my spring-boot war file to `../standalone/deployments/`, the error message:

> Failed to register application at spring-boot-admin

shows up in the logs.

Also, I cannot access my api at `localhost:8080` the way I was able to using embedded tomcat and spring boot.

I'm lost as to how to troubleshoot this issue. Any thoughts?

**Edit**: I start wildfly with `-b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0`

**Edit:**: Found out that my app will be accessible at `localhost:8080/$myAppNAme`. Still no luck.